# How to properly handle focus of children in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I'm having a problem handling the focus of a child `Node`. I have this custom layout with a bunch of nodes in its hierarchy, and I'd like to make one of its children (specifically, a `Pane`) to be `focusTraversable` or can obtain focus on mouse pressed (like a button control). What I really want to do is simply change the background color of the child when focused, here's my code:

```
Pane pane = new Pane();
pane.getStyleClass().setAll("container");
pane.setFocusTraversable(true);
pane.setOnMousePressed(event -> {
  if (!pane.isFocused() && pane.isFocusTraversable()) {
    pane.requestFocus();
    // Test if this node is currently focused
    System.out.println(pane.isFocused());
  }
});
```

CSS changes the `-fx-background-color` of the pane:

```
.container {
  -fx-background-color: red;
}
.container:focused {
  -fx-background-color: blue;
}
```

Although it appears that the node is focused when traversing using `TAB` key, the background does not change at all when it is pressed. So, what was the proper way of handling focus of children?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the `Pane` receives focus when pressing `TAB` but not when pressing the mouse? If so, knowing the current focus owner might help. Which `Node` has the focus when you attempt to click on the `Pane`? You can test this with [`Scene.focusOwnerProperty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html#focusOwnerProperty()). Another possible issue could be your `Pane` is "covered" by another `Node` that is not [mouse transparent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#mouseTransparentProperty()).

Comment: @Slaw I don't know what was causing this, but the focus was passed onto the `ScrollPane` after the `Pane` itself. The hierarchy is like this: `Root` > `ScrollPane` > `VBox` > `Parent` > `Child` (where `Child` was the `Pane` and the `VBox` was the content of `ScrollPane`). I still had no idea how to manage this.

Comment: In the `EventHandler` you use for `setOnMousePressed` try consuming the `MouseEvent` (e.g. `event.consume()`). It's possible that `ScrollPane` requests focus when the `MouseEvent` bubbles up to it.

Comment: @Slaw Yes, I guess consuming the event is necessary as part of proper handling of focus. Thank you sir.